# SELECT, how to combine some rows as one, show rows with specific column value first and exclude a row

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

I have two tables, `units` and `power`. 
 Take a look at:

The **`power`** table:

```
+----+-------+
| id | power |
+----+-------+
|  1 |     2 |
|  2 |     4 |
|  3 |     6 |
|  4 |     8 |
+----+-------+
```

The **`units`** table:

```
 +----+---------+----------+--------+----------+---+---+
    | id | user_id | power_id | amount | group_id | x | y |
    +----+---------+----------+--------+----------+---+---+
    |  1 |      10 |        3 |   1000 |        0 | 1 | 1 |
    |  2 |      10 |        3 |   1000 |        0 | 1 | 1 |
    |  3 |      10 |        3 |   1000 |        0 | 1 | 1 |
    |  4 |      11 |        2 |    100 |        4 | 1 | 1 |
    |  5 |      11 |        2 |    100 |        4 | 1 | 1 |
    |  6 |      11 |        1 |    100 |        4 | 1 | 1 |
    |  7 |      12 |        4 |   1000 |        0 | 1 | 1 |
    +----+---------+----------+--------+----------+---+---+
```

I want to get result looking like this:

```
+----------+--------------+-------------+----------+---------+--+
| units.id | total_amount | total_power | group_id | user_id |  |
+----------+--------------+-------------+----------+---------+--+
|        3 |         1000 |        6000 |        0 |      10 |  |
|        2 |         1000 |        6000 |        0 |      10 |  |
|        4 |          300 |        1000 |        4 |      11 |  |
|        7 |         1000 |        8000 |        0 |      12 |  |
+----------+--------------+-------------+----------+---------+--+
```

Explanation:

1. Exclude a specific id, should work same for both a single row and a row which is a sum of multiple rows in the table. As you see, in the result set, row with id 1 was excluded. The id is provided by the app, I think it's better to do it in MySQL than PHP, because MySQL could just discard this row (I think), but with PHP it would have to do if() checking for every loop iteration, which seems less efficient.
2. Show the summed-rows row before single rows, every time.
3. Show user's units before other users', every time. You can see that when rows with **user_id** of **10** (imagine this user is the one seeing the page) appear first in my result set.
4. Show units with highest power first.
5. Show units with highest amount first.
6. Show units with highest id first.

The last(4.5.6) are sorted in regards to the priority of the result set, with 4th having the most of it.
I have this query:

```
SELECT   units.id,
         units.amount*power.power AS total_power,
         Sum(units.amount)        AS total_amount
FROM     units
JOIN     power
ON       units.power_id = power.id
WHERE    x = ?
AND      y = 1
GROUP BY group_id
ORDER BY group_id desc, total_power desc, total_amount desc, units.id desc limit ?,?
```

But it combines all units where `group_id` is 0, however I want units with **`group_id=0`** to be separate rows in the result set. How to do that? Thanks!

**Edit**: To answer @Linoff's question about how I determine which id to exclude, I exclude the **`1`** in the example because a user always will see the result set through accessing it with a unit_id, which, again, in my example happens to be **1**. I hope it is clear now.
**Edit**: The user can access this list of units on page "**index.php?page=unit/view&id=**. Then I SELECT the entered id separately for the purpose of my app, and then SELECT the list. But as I already have data for the entered id (for instance, 1 in this case) I do not need to have them when I SELECT from the `units` and `power`.

@Anonymous, to answer your question 1, answer 1 is: all rows with same group_id (except 0 which is a `not-a-group` marker) are grouped and combined together, so rows which are id `4`,`5` and `6` which have identical `group_id` are combined. My problem is, I don't know how to exclude grouping for rows which are stand alone (no group marking) and how to sort the result so the rows with specified user_id are sorted first and grouped rows (4,5,6-turned-to-4) are also sorted first, but in user_id=10-first,user_id=??-second hierarchy, if this makes sense.

Comment: How you determine the rows in your result set totally baffles me.  If "1" is discarded, why not "2"?  The rows are exactly the same.

Comment: I do not get this summing up, yet show them separately at all. Either you group in a query, or you do not, but you can't have it both ways. You have to use two queries for this end, which can be combined in an outer query, but may be simpler to do so in php.

Comment: Q1: unit.id=5 is group=4. why it beomes group=0? Q2: what happened to unit.id=6 and 7 in the result set?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have edited the question to answer you. Please check it.

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ  I have edited the question to answer you. Please check it.

Comment: @Shadow I need to show the groups together, however I don't want MySQL to see group_id=0 as a group. I need it to just select group_id=0 rows separately, and group only the ones with group_id > 0. So, I will have to make two queries either in MySQL, or with PHP, you mean?

Comment: @MoeEpo . . . The selection of rows still makes no sense to me.  I look at the input data, I read your explanation, and I don't see the relationship between the rows in one and the rows in the other.   
You specify that "1" is purposefully removed, but what about 6 and 7? 
 Normally, a query like this would be a `join` and `group by`.  Perhaps it might include `roll up`.  But I just don't see it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am sorry for my mistake. There are no purpose in changing the ids, I see now. Thanks, I will correct the question.

Comment: i will pass on this one. nothing makes sense to me. need more coffee perhaps.

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ Thank for attempting, anyway.